# Why does the mouse over review badge progress not show up in the "Choose which badge to track"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badge-request

When one is going through a Review queue, there is a pop up dialog when you hover over the mini progress bar, which shows one's progress towards the Reviewer badge like so:

> [image: Review Badge progress on Robotics]

However, on the "Choose which badge to track" pop-up dialog, on the user's profile page, that same progress is not shown, see here:

> [image: Robotics Review badge not shown on Choose which badge to track]

Here is another example, this time from Arduino:

Review queue

> [image: Review Badge progress on Arduino]

Profile page

> [image: Arduino Review badge not shown on Choose which badge to track]

Am I missing something, or is this intentional?

Comment: My expectation is that in each case, the user already has a Reviewer badge in a different queue. The profile page will only ever track the first instance of each badge.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - That would make sense, but as you can see from the Robotics Silver only "Choose which badge to track" pop up dialog, I do not yet have that badge. I've just checked my Arduino badge list, and I don't appear to have achieved it there either.

Comment: Sure enough. I'm not sure what the deal is, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that is because that badge can be awarded multiple times (once for every review queue). The other review badges (those that are awarded once) are in the list.

Tracking this badge would be rather difficult: for which review queue should it show the statistics? What if you are tracking one and the other outscores it?

I think the developers just took the easiest way by just not showing them. (They have excluded some other badges for various reasons, mainly performance, which isn't the case here).

Comment: Fair enough. Understood. Thx.

Comment: Just my first guess from a developers POV.